# Laravel 5 SSL - is encrypted with obsolete cryptography

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, encryption, laravel-5

I haven't used an SSL certificate before and was curious to whether this is a Certificate issue or something I am doing incorrect.

I have purchased an SSL certificate which is running on my server. I am using Laravel 5. I am using the MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 cipher.

In Google chrome is displays the following

Your connection to ... is encrypted with obsolete technology.

The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and ECDHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

Is there something I need to change, or do I not need to worry about this?

Comment: This article might be helpful: [Why Google is Hurrying the Web to Kill SHA-1](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)

Comment: Thank you, thats very useful, will investigate to see if my certificate is using SHA-1. So does that refer to my certificate, rather than anything set in Laravel

Comment: Yes this has nothing to do with Laravel. Google Chrome can't possibly know about what framework and hashing algorithm is running on your server... (also Laravel uses Bcrypt which is pretty safe ;))

Answer (score 0):

10 days ago this question was answered here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/google-chrome-your-connection-to-website-is-encrypted-with-obsolete-cryptograph

For "modern cryptography" you should use authenticated encryption. Google Chrome supports AES_128_GCM and CHACHA20_POLY1305.

Google is killing SHA1 as a certificate signature algorithm, not a message authentication code. Currently, when Chrome sees obsolete cryptography, its behaviour doesn't change.

Comment: So is this something I am doing or my provider? Basically I purchased an ssl from Heartinternet and they installed it on the server. They are saying it's to do with other items on the page. But the only thing I have is a link to use Google auth. Which would be googles ssl. I doubt Google is causing this. I keep arguing with them as I don't see how this is something I am doing. I ran and ssl test and the results came back as a chain certificate was using the weal sha1.

Comment: @ChrisTownsend Your case is using 256-bit encryption that needs a separate message authentication code. Instead, you should use Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data. Chrome currently supports both 128-bit and 256-bit AEAD (AES_128_GCM and CHACHA20_POLY1305 respectively). These ciphers are available only in the latest TLS version, so make sure you are using TLS 1.2.

Comment: The answer provided in the linked one does not apply to the asked question properly. It states using ECDHE_RSA instead of plain RSA, is enough, which is obviously wrong since the warning being the subject of the current question explicitely says that AES_256_CBC with ECDHE_RSA is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

@lukasgeiter actually hold the answer in the comments:

[Google blog](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.fr/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) states:

> Chrome will start the process of sunsetting SHA-1 (as used in certificate signatures for HTTPS) with Chrome 39 in November. HTTPS sites whose certificate chains use SHA-1 and are valid past 1 January 2017 will no longer appear to be fully trustworthy in Chrome’s user interface.

Answer (score 0):

In [November 2014](https://codereview.chromium.org/703143003), code was checked into the chromium project that changes the messages shown in the Connection dialog.

Previously, the wording stated the bit level of the encryption of the connection, which could be misleading.

Now, Chrome will [label the connection as modern](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls) if it is >= TLS 1.2 AND uses Forward Secrecy (e.g. ECDHE_RSA) AND an AEAD cipher (either AES-GCM or CHACHA20_POLY1305). Otherwise, it will be labeled as obsolete.

If you are able to configure the server yourself, and have determined you want to configure it to support a modern profile, [Mozilla's SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) is a good place to start.

See also Mozilla's [Security/Server Side TLS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) wiki page for more information.